# Count number of valid password based on some given restrictions

Tags: c++, regex

I have to count how many valid passwords are possible based on some given restrictions. The restrictions are following:

1. Minimum `10` characters and Maximum `14` characters.
2. Characters can include small English letters (`'a'-'z'`), Capital letters (`'A'-'Z'`), digits (`'0'-'9'`) and special characters (`'!','@','#','$','%','^','&','*','(',')'`)
3. Valid passwords must contain at least one of small letter, capital letter, digit and special character each.
4. Passwords cannot contain own student ID. Students ID are of 7 digits. First two digits denote year (`00, 01, ... , 99`), next two digits denote department code (`00, 01, ... 99`), and last three digits denote roll inside a department (`000 - 180`). So a student ID can be like: `1210142`, where `12` denotes he is from batch `12`, `10` is department code, and `142` is roll number. A student with ID `1210142` cannot have a password like `Ti@s1210142mE` but can have password like `Ti@s121014m2E`.
5. A student can use another student's ID in his/her own password.

Given the restrictions how many valid passwords can be generated?

I wrote a simple C++ program to simulate it. But as it is just a naive implementation, it would require a whole lot of time (maybe greater than my lifetime) to spit out an answer. Is there any clever way to figuring out the answer using code, possibly using regex or something like that?

My effort so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

inline bool is_valid_password(const std::string &generated_password, const std::string &student_id){
    bool small = false, captial = false, digit = false, special = false;
    for(const char &c : generated_password){
        if(c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') small = true;
        else if(c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') captial = true;
        else if(c >= '0' && c <= '9') digit = true;
        else if(c == '!' || c == '@' || c == '#' || c == '$' || c == '%' || c == '^' || c == '&' || c == '*' || c == '(' || c == ')') special = true;
    }
    if(small && captial && digit && special){
        return generated_password.find(student_id) == std::string::npos;
    }
    return false;
}

char valid_character_set [] = {
        'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z',
        'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z',
        '0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9',
        '!','@','#','$','%','^','&','*','(',')'
};

long long comb(int N, int K, const std::string &student_id)
{
    std::string bitmask(K, 1); // K leading 1's
    bitmask.resize(N, 0); // N-K trailing 0's

    long long counter = 0;

    // print integers and permute bitmask
    do {
        std::string generated_password = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) // [0..N-1] integers
        {
            if (bitmask[i]){
                generated_password += valid_character_set[i];
            }
        }

        if(is_valid_password(generated_password, student_id)) {
            //std::cout << "valid password found: " << generated_password << '\n';
            counter++;
        }

    } while (std::prev_permutation(bitmask.begin(), bitmask.end()));

    return counter;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    std::cout << "Enter your student id: ";
    std::string student_id; std::cin >> student_id;
    std::cout << "Your student id is: " << student_id << "\n";



    // all possible 10 character passwords

    std::cout << comb(72, 10, student_id) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you can check if the string contains the student ID of the current student. If not, then you might use a pattern with lookarounds (if supported) to validate the character requirements:  `^(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=[^0-9]*[0-9])(?=[^!@#$%^&*()]*[!@#$%^&*()])[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*()]{10,14}$` https://regex101.com/r/rEOPxD/1

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are familiar with writing regex, but if not, you can learn and try out a lot on [this website](https://regex101.com/). In my opinion, regex is a very powerful concept and it is worth it to invest some time to learn it.

Anyway, when you are familiar with regex, there is a *very* useful [standard library for regex](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/) in C++. Just include

```
#include<regex>
```

And then you can instantiated your own regex object:

```
std::regex r = regex("yourRegexPattern");
```

With that object, you can invoke some useful functions, like `regex_match()` (which could be the right one for your use case), `regex_search()` or `regex_replace()`.

For more information, I have linked the official reference above, or you can just google "c++ regex"

Edit: fixed links